# Is it possible to update an image layer while panning in OpenLayers 7?

Tags: openlayers

I am looking for a way to update an image layer while panning the map (holding down the mouse button), like the option `updateWhileInteracting` in [vector layers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html) or the old `loadTilesWhileInteracting` for the [map object](https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html).

The default behavior in OpenLayers 7 is to wait to re-render the image until you release the mouse button.

I am using the packages ol 7.1.0 and proj4js 2.8.0.

This code is similar to what I have:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import Static from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import View from 'ol/View';
import proj4 from 'proj4';
import {Image as ImageLayer, Tile as TileLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {getCenter} from 'ol/extent';
import {register} from 'ol/proj/proj4';
import {transform} from 'ol/proj';

proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:27700',
  '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 ' +
    '+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy ' +
    '+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 ' +
    '+units=m +no_defs'
);
register(proj4);

const imageExtent = [0, 0, 700000, 1300000];
const imageLayer = new ImageLayer();

const map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    imageLayer,
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: transform(getCenter(imageExtent), 'EPSG:27700', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 4,
  }),
});

const interpolate = document.getElementById('interpolate');

function setSource() {
  const source = new Static({
    url:
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/18/' +
      'British_National_Grid.svg/2000px-British_National_Grid.svg.png',
    crossOrigin: '',
    projection: 'EPSG:27700',
    imageExtent: imageExtent,
    interpolate: interpolate.checked,
  });
  imageLayer.setSource(source);
}
setSource();

interpolate.addEventListener('change', setSource);
```

External runnable demo code (based on this [ol example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-image.html)): https://github.com/cascading-jox/pan-and-update-gis

Comment: @TomazicM My bad. I'll make sure to add some code asap.

Comment: Result of your `setSource` function is dependent only on `interpolate.checked` value and is not dependent on map moving/panning. Calling `setSource` during map pan wouldn't change anything.